# How to change Google task status from completed to Pending?

Tags: api, google-tasks-api

I am working on Google task api
When i update task status from needAction to complete it change perfectly.
But when change from completed to anything(Pending/needAction)
It gives error means status not change when once it set to completed.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an new Task, exactly same as current, and put into queue.

Comment: solved : when i search i found if we first get task object.we get it in dictionary format.than delete "completed" element from task dictionary ,and change status "needsAction" after this changes update that task.

Comment: Did you tested it in production system?